# Unable to connect to internet using conduit nodered application

Tags: node-red, conduit, lora

I am trying to connect my multitech conduit to IoT through node-red application from multitech. My conduit is connected to the internet.

When I add a HTTP or TCP node it is not connecting and gives me an `Enotfound` error.

Could you please let me know if this is because the node red application is not able to access internet? What are the possible ways to connect it to the internet?

Comment: Hi Partheepan. Please, expand your question, adding examples and the whole error you are getting.

Comment: You should share your Node-RED flow at least if you really need help.